# undefined (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Yes, I've read multiple threads on this topic but I still can't get my project to work: In My `App.js` I have a conditional rendering of a Login Screen or to render the  Screen. This is also where my `AppContainer` lives. The method `handleAddSubmit=()=>{}` triggered by a button in my Header gives me the undefined error. Any suggestions?

### App.js

```
return(
      <View>
        <AppNav/>
        <Main
          username={this.state.username}
          onLoggedOut={this.LoggedOut}
          />
      </View>
    );
```

### Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import { Header} from 'react-native-elements';
import IntervalSelector from './HourCards/IntervalSelector'
import HourCard from './HourCards/HourCard'

 export default class Main extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
}

handleAddSubmit = () =>
{
   this.props.navigation.navigate('ToggleNewHourFile');
}

  render() {
    const {username} = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
      <Header
        centerComponent={{ text: '[ ' + username + ' ]',
          style: { color: '#fff',
          fontFamily: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight' : 'Roboto',
      fontSize:20 } }}
    backgroundColor='#18153f'
    rightComponent=
    {{
      icon: 'home',
      color: '#fff',
      onPress: this.handleHomeSubmit,
      underlayColor: 'transparent',
    }}
    leftComponent=
    {{
      icon: 'add',
      color: '#fff',
      onPress: this.handleAddSubmit,
      underlayColor: 'transparent',
    }}
    statusBarProps={{barStyle:"light-content", translucent:'true'}}
    />
    <IntervalSelector/>
    <View>
    <ScrollView>
    <HourCard/>
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

### StackNavigator.js

```
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import Main from '../main/Main';
import ToggleNewHourFile from '../main/HourCards/ToggleNewHourFile';

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
  Main: { screen: Main },
  ToggleNewHourFile: {screen: ToggleNewHourFile},
  }
);

const AppNav = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);

export default AppNav;
```

### ToggleNewHourFile.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';

class ToggleNewHourFile extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Text>Hallo</Text>
    )
  }
}
export default ToggleNewHourFile;
```

Comment: Changes createStackNavigator to createSwitchNavigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference `Main` in your stack navigator and also in your App.js.  The `Main` in App.js does not have access to the stack navigator which is what's causing the error.

You can explicitly pass the navigator as a prop to `Main`, for example:

```
  navigator;
  ...
  <View>
    <AppNav ref={nav => this.navigator = nav}/>
    <Main
      navigation={this.navigator}
      username={this.state.username}
      onLoggedOut={this.LoggedOut}
      />
```

or you can refactor your code to remove the `Main` component from App.js